# Add A view with Dissolve effect in iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

```
FlipView *fl=[[FlipView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipView" bundle:nil];
//fl.view.frame=CGRectMake(50.0,50.0, 300.0,300.0);
fl.delegate=self;
fl.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
fl.imageName=aCategoryDtl.Tip_Image;
[self presentModalViewController:fl animated:YES];
```

---

In above code, A Complete New View Controller is added to screen.

Instead of that, I need to display only single view(UIView) - Not View controller.(UIViewController)

How to implement that?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: I think maybe you are confused. A view controller has no on screen elements it is purely a construct within memory used to manage on screen views.

Comment: @Corey Floyd - Sir, Actually - Here I had given the example that how a viewcontroller works with the Dissolve effect. By giving that example I wanted to tell the reader - that - "I want this kind of effect"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment is correct, you do not display a view controller, u display that viewcontrollers views, viewControllers are used to manage views, now what i imagine you want is a way to switch from view to view with transitions in a single view controller, there is a sample project called ViewTransition here https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ViewTransitions/ it contains a view that you can use to switch from view to view with transitions, it might help you

Comment: @Daniel - Sir, You understood me.

Comment: That's a great example. Thanks a lot.